# Error (0xc0000022) during start explorer.exe after log in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Hi I have problem with start Windows 7 x86. After I input credentials in log on screen

I get this error:

**eplorer.exe**

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022). Click OK to close the application.

[image]

I google it but I can find a solution I found this:  http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0000022-457663.html

I dont understand this:

> Issue related to CA Internet Suite. log into "safe mode" and
>   **uninstalled the entire suite.** restart computer.

I use Windows 7 and I dont have CA Internet Suite in my system. I checked Programs and Fetueres this appp is not included in the list.

So I dont have CA Internet Suite?

Thank you for support...

Answer (score 2):

`0xC0000022` [means](http://www.koders.com/c/fid8FB3BB72BB3BD864A2399EA591F36997F9566CC9.aspx) `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` and is the result of file access that fails, this often happens due to permission problems but can rarely happen when a DLL fails to load or was not found.

Here are your options:

- [CTX184036](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX184036) handles this issue with regards to the error, by giving Everyone permissions on 3 files.
- Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to identify whether other files get the ACCESS DENIED status with a boot log.
- With [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html), disable anything that is not from Microsoft, you can sort by the Company column.
- Install the C++ redistributable packs of which these files originate: [2005 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5638), [2008 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5582), [2010 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328)

Answer (score 1):

Your link tells you to uninstall 'CA internet suite'

Comment: I checked Programs and Fetueres this appp is not included in the list.

So I dont have CA Internet Suite?

Answer (score 0):

I use git, which managed to change the file permissions for the DLLs this program needs. 
I fixed it by setting the permissions on my DLLs to full control.

Comment: This sounds *very* insecure.